# Error while creating form

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm trying to create a basic form by referring the guide from [tutorial](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/10?orm=Doctrine)

This is my version of form

```
class UsersForm extends BaseUsersForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
      $this->useFields(["name,email"]);

      $this->setWidgetSchema("email") = new sfWidgetFormInputText();
      $this->setWidgetSchema("name") = new sfWidgetFormInputText();

      $this->validatorSchema["email"] = new sfValidatorEmail();
      $this->validatorSchema["name"] =new sfValidatorString(["max_length" => "30"]);

      $this->widgetSchema->setLabels([

          "email" => "Email Address",
          "name" => "User name"

      ]);

  }
}
```

And I got this error

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Please tell me if I did wrong any part of the code.

Comment: dont use symfony1, its almost as old as me.

Comment: Symfony 1.4 is not maintained anymore, you should not waste your time learning it, learn Symfony2 instead

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: my version of php is 5.5

Comment: Do the error says in which line is the problem?

Answer (score 8):

There are several errors in your code, beginning with:

`$this->useFields(["name,email"]);`

where you probably wanted to write:

`$this->useFields(["name", "email"]);`

The fatal error you're getting is because of this snippet (you're trying to assign a value to function return value):

```
$this->setWidgetSchema("email") = new sfWidgetFormInputText();
$this->setWidgetSchema("name") = new sfWidgetFormInputText();
```

a better version would be:

```
$arWidgets = [
   "email" => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
   "name" => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
];

$arValidators = [
   "email" => new sfValidatorEmail(),
   "name" => new sfValidatorString(["max_length" => "30"]),
];

$this->setWidgets($arWidgets);
$this->setValidators($arValidators);
```

After applying these changes your problem should be solved.